# Sysbench test Mysql but no disk read

Tags: mysql, buffer, sysbench

When I use sysbench to test mysql, I use `iotop` to monitor io and I find only have `DiSH WRITE` speed, the `DISK READ` speed is always 0. Then I use `free -h` and I find that buffer/cache increase, does it mean that sysbench's test data is not write in disk but in buffer and no auto update into disk?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where is the mysql running ?? I dont know about iotop and what its measuring but even tiny sysbench runs generate enormous IO. it could be a user issue maybe, perhaps mysql is generating io under a different user and not getting picked up.

```sh
# you can isolate the db into a container and run sysbench against this to see
# if/when/how much IO there is.

docker run --rm -it --name mdb105 --network host -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=on mariadb:10.5 --port=10306

# in another terminal run
docker stats

# now run sysbench, and you will see enormous IO

# you can get another shell in container named mdb105 by:
docker exec -it --user root mdb105 bash

# mariadb:10.5 is based on ubuntu:20.04
# you could maybe run iotop inside the container
```

Update: I was able to replicate something like your zero IO situation using a raspberry pi. indeed docker stats shows no IO while clearly data is being saved to disk. my initial reaction was that maybe some kernels/distro are missing certain facilities, but it looks like its not kernel/distro because i saw IO when playing around with disk/fs ie extenal USB disk ... i think it was more to do with the micro sd card and its controller/drivers that dont support this kind of stats. and since your tps is very low i suspect you are on something similar to micro sd as well.

this likely wont happen in a ec2 instance.

Comment: Mysql run in docker, and this is a part of sysbench logout `[ 5s ] thds: 10 tps: 62.93 qps: 1296.52 (r/w/o: 908.96/259.70/127.85) lat (ms,95%): 411.96 err/s: 0.00 reconn/s: 0.00`, It means that mysql have both read and write operations, but when I use `docker stats` to monitor mysql, I observe that READ in BLOCK I/O is not increase.

Comment: the numbers are somewhat low. 10 tps and 62 queries per second ?? I would expect way more tps and qps from even a single core machine. still if you let it run for a couple minutes you should see IO in docker stats. how did you prep the database ?? or did you even run a sysbench prep command ?? post your sysbench commands. also do you still have the mysql running on the host when you ran the ephemeral container ?? if so its possible it connected to the host again silently, maybe over unix domain socket

Comment: added more info to the post.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My TPS is 62.93; 10 is threads. Mysql run in docker and NO mysql  on the host. sysbench prepare command is `sysbench oltp_read_write.lua --tables=10 --table_size=300000 --threads=10 --rand-type=uniform --db-driver=mysql --mysql-db=sysbench --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=123456 --mysql-host=192.168.1.206 --mysql-port=3306 prepare` and similar to run command. What bothers me is Mysql Write a lot of data to disk BUT almost no Read from disk.

Comment: And this are some info from `/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/docker/mysql/blkio.io_service_bytes`:                                                                                                                                                                     
`8:0 Read 856064`
`8:0 Write 1904771072`
`8:0 Sync 1905627136`
`8:0 Async 0`
`8:0 Total 1905627136`
`Total 1905627136`     as you see, Write is much bigger than Read...